# IP camera with RTSP on the web, RED5 and ffmpeg

Tags: camera, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

i have a ip camera with rtsp protocol and i want to stream on the web using flash video. I know i can use vlc but i do not want to use that.

I installed red5 and ffmpeg for convert RTSP to RTMP

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://46.13.85.43:8020/ch0.h264" -f flv -r 25 -s 640x480 -an "rtmp://localhost/live"
```

and result is: UDP timeout. retrying with TCP

Any idea where is the problem ?

Comment: what if you just do ffmpeg -i "rtsp://46.13.85.43:8020/ch0.h264" ? what command works with vlc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that tcp protocol is used, or at least that helped me. Please add this parameter ***-rtsp_transport tcp*** to your ffmpeg command.